# Creating Xaringan HTML presentation with HTML widgets and retaining widgets and formatting when attaching or uploading HTML file

Tags: r, xaringan

I have created a Xaringan presentation with HTML widgets and custom formatting through CSS file modification. When I try to send the HTML file as an attachment via email or upload the HTML file to a site, none of the widgets or formatting are preserved. Is this normal Xaringan behavior? Is there a way to output the presentation in such a way that the contents are preserved when sharing as an attachment or a site upload?

Comment: I suspect that you haven't send the other necessary files e.g. CSS etc. Self-contained xaringan slides needs work at the moment: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/3

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give up on self-contained slides at the moment. For bonus points can you explain the source of the dependency? Once HTML file is created, why/how does presentation require additional files?

Comment: Because css files describe the style, images are not contained in html etc